# How to create multidimensional array with multitype?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I used to create this kind of arrays in PHP:

```
$myarray[0]["my_string_1"] = "Toto";
$myarray[0]["my_string_2"] = "Tata";
$myarray[0]["my_int_1"] = 25;
$myarray[0]["my_int_2"] = 28;
$myarray[1]["my_string_1"] = "Titi";
$myarray[1]["my_string_2"] = "Tutu";
$myarray[1]["my_int_1"] = 12;
$myarray[1]["my_int_2"] = 15;
```

My question is: 
Is it possible to do the same thing in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not familiar with PHP but it looks like your array has a 'map' of string to string or int. This can be done in C# using a Dictionary and Dynamic:

```
var myarray = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, dynamic>>()
{
    {
        0, new Dictionary<string, dynamic>()
        {
            {"my_string_1", "Toto"},
            {"my_string_2", "Tata"},
            {"my_int_1", 25},
            {"my_int_2", 28},
        }
    },
    {
        1, new Dictionary<string, dynamic>()
        {
            {"my_string_1", "Titi"},
            {"my_string_2", "Tutu"},
            {"my_int_1", 12},
            {"my_int_2", 15},
        }
    }
};
```

See the documentation for more info on [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Dynamic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx).

**Edit:**

As others have suggested, you might be better off using:

```
var myarray = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, object>>()
```

And instead of using a dictionary with an `int` as the key, an actual array could be used:

```
var myarray = new Dictionary<string, object>[2];
myarray[0] = new Dictionary<string, object>
{

    {"my_string_1", "Toto"},
    {"my_string_2", "Tata"},
    {"my_int_1", 25},
    {"my_int_2", 28},
};
myarray[1] = new Dictionary<string, object>
{

    {"my_string_1", "Titi"},
    {"my_string_2", "Tutu"},
    {"my_int_1", 12},
    {"my_int_2", 15},
};
```

Comment: It could also be a `Dictionary<string, dynamic>[]`.

Comment: Important to remember that you have to *create* the inner dictionaries.They don't appear by auto-magic

Comment: Why dynamic? why not object?

Comment: As I wrote, not familiar with PHP, I figured it's a dynamically typed language

Comment: I'd say go with `object` instead of `dynamic`.